# Flutter Firebase timestamp searchquery

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my apps user can post. And post store in firebase like this 
[image]

I wanna fetch my all post which posted in last week. I need some filter in my search query. But I dont know how can I. 
 this my search query

```
_newQuerySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("posts")
      .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
      .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
      .limit(5)
      .getDocuments();
```

I need like this .where( //posted in last week ) 
Please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can do like this

```
var startfulldate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new 
Date(1556062581000));
db.collection('mycollection')
  .where('start_time', '<=', startfulldate)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {              
        var jsonvalue: any[] = [];
        snapshot.forEach(docs => {
          jsonvalue.push(docs.data())
           })
             res.send(jsonvalue);
             return;
            }).catch( error => {
                res.status(500).send(error)
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved like this.

```
 var beginningDate = DateTime.now();
        var newDate=beginningDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));



          _newQuerySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
              .collection("posts").where("createdAt",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: newDate)
              .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
              .limit(5)
              .getDocuments();
```